# Graphql can't retrieve sub type

Tags: express, graphql, resolver

I'm new on graphql and i tried to implement a basic API with express.

But, when i tried to request post author these return null.

My "Post" type :

```
const postType = `
    type Post {
        id: ID
        title: String
        content: String
        author: User
    }
`;

module.exports = postType
```

My "User" type :

```
const userType = `
    type User {
        id: ID
        name: String
        age: Int
    }
`;

module.exports = userType
```

My Graphql API schema :

```
const schema = buildSchema(`
    ${userType}
    ${postType}
    type Query {
        users: [User!]!
        posts: [Post!]!
        user(id: Int): User!
        post(id: Int): Post!
    }
    type Mutation {
        createUser(user: createUserInput): User
    }
    schema {
        query: Query
        mutation: Mutation
    }
`);

module.exports = schema
```

My "Post" resolver and type implementation with ES6 class :

```
const { getUser } = require('../actions/index').user
const { getPost, getPosts } = require('../actions/index').post

class Post {
    constructor(post) {
        Object.assign(this, post)
    }

    async author() {
        const data = await getUser(this.post.author)
        return data
    }
}


const postResolver = {
    posts: async () => {
        const data = await getPosts()
        return data.map(post => new Post(post))
    },
    post: async ({ id }) => new Post(await getPost(id))
}

module.exports = postResolver
```

My "User" resolver and type implementation with ES6 class :

```
const { getUsers, getUser, createUser } = require('../actions/index').user

class User {
  constructor(user) {
    Object.assign(this, user)
  }
}

const userResolver = {
  users: async () => {
    const data = await getUsers()
    return data.map(user => new User(user))
  },
  user: async ({ id }) => new User(await getUser(id)),
}

module.exports = userResolver
```

The client query and response :

```
query {
  post(id: 1) {
    id
    title
    author {
      id
    } 
  }
}

// response
{
  "data": {
    "post": {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "Post 1",
      "author": {
        "id": null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Someone can help me please ? Thanks !

Comment: what tutorial followed? is `Post.author()` called?, what returns? shouldn't it be `return new User( getUser...` ? missing `User` class/type resolver? etc.

Comment: Sorry, to complete:
I used this tutorial on YT https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7b4HxdQuevk.
It implements something very similar, in my case Post.author () is not called.
But effectively this method should return a user instance.

Comment: follow come better/more complete tutorials ... 'field resolver' not called - it's not enough to be a class method (not related/connected to type/field resolver) ... https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/resolvers/

Comment: ok thank you, I will see in this direction